# What is the difference between plugin and modules in Zend?

Tags: module, zend-framework2

If I download a chat software on word press, it is called a `Plugin`. In Zend Framework it's called a `Module`, but there is also plugin's for Controllers.

What's the difference between modules and plugins in Zend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module in zf2 is similar to a plugin in wordpress yes! They are a collection of different classes that can be loaded into a project and allow either for reuse of generic code in other projects (this would be using composer in zf2) or modules can simply be used as groupings for similar code in a project.

zf2 is itself modular (I could just load some of the modules in my project, they are designed to work standalone) but lets not do that here

composer.json

```
{  
"name": "myApp",

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",

    "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.3.0",
    "zf-commons/zfc-twig": "dev-1.2rc1"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Application": "module/Application/src/"
    }
}
}
```

providing composer is installed I can just run:

```
composer update
```

from the command line. If you haven't had much experience with composer, the docs ain't bad https://getcomposer.org/doc/ but it is a must have for zf2 development!

Then in the root of your app you can then add to config.application.config.php your modules

```
return array(
'modules' => array(
    'zfTwig',
    'MyCustomModule',
),
}
```

Now these modules are available in your project. For more information see

http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/01/21/some-tips-to-write-better-zend-framework-2-modules/

and

http://mwop.net/blog/267-Getting-started-writing-ZF2-modules.html

You can also add modules yourself at the application level (as I said previously these are more for grouping features or whatever you fancy together).

You can use this to help build your personal modules

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule

Just place the ZendSkeletonModule in the module folder of your zf2 app and update all the namespaces and the root folder of the module to match. In the case of the application.config.php I have above you would rename it all "MyCustomModule".

A controller plugin is something quite different, they are just a class which is registered to be injected into a controller basically

They can be called in your controllers to perform certain tasks.

The FlashMessenger plugin for example allows you to register a message in the flash messenger within your controller that will be displayed on the next page load.

From the zf2 docs

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('You are now logged in.');
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user-success');
```

see http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html for more detail

Comment: This is another good blog post abouts modules http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/modules-in-zf2/ another must read!

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for the elaborative answer. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

**Modules**

> A module is a self contained collection of code that provides similar functionality within an application.

This means modules can be anything you desire them to be (one file or your whole application!).

'Modules' are not new terminology in ZF2; "Modular Programming" has been around for a long time. By having logical groups of code functionality it will promote code reuse and the '[open close principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)'.

**Modules in ZF2**

Modules are first class citizens within Zend Framework 2; this means that the framework was designed specifically for the purpose of being able to add and remove modules with ease.

There are many [examples of ZF2 modules online](http://modules.zendframework.com/) - Most of which would require minor configuration changes and you can begin using them (code reuse!)

**Plugins**

Again a generic term that will have different meanings in different frameworks. You may have heard of 'pluggable software', [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616502/pluggable-design) summaries it nicely.

> [A design for when] you want a system to work in straightforward and predictable ways, with very specific points of variation.

The 'points of variation' are areas of your code that are likely to require changes or different logic. A system that allows for external sources to be injected without the base code being modified is thought to be 'plugable'.

**Plugins in ZF2**

A 'Plugin' in ZF2 is actually known as a '[Controller plugin](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-flashmessenger)'

They are classes designed to add functionality to Controllers (any class extending `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController`), without the need to extend the controller class.

Some examples of this are the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger` which allows you to add a message to session and display it on the reloaded page. This can be reused in all your controllers without needing to modify them.